# Integrate Jenkins with Sourcetree

Tags: git, jenkins, atlassian-sourcetree

I have used jenkins with selenium before, but sourcetree is entirely new for me, I have all my codecept js test files committed in sourcetree. And would like to integrate it with jenkins, is there a way to do that? Jenkins integration with codeceptjs?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need to integrate Jenkins with the Git repository manager SourceTree.

You should be able to simply use a [BitBucket Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Plugin) in order to get the sources from your remote Atlassian repo into a Jenkins workspace.